# Sharepoint- Trim column up to specific character

Tags: sharepoint, trim

I am trying to trim a column up to a specific character. This column is created when an email is sent to the sharepoint site. Here is an example:

John Smith (1234567890_carrier.net)Login_Report

I just want to get John Smith and there is always an ( after the name.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying to trim - where? In a calculated column, a workflow, client side, server side?

Answer (score 1):

Without programming, you can create an additional calculated column in your list that would use the formula language to cut the unwanted text from the name:. Let us say that the column  with the full text is MyColumn:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("(";MyColumn));LEFT(MyColumn;FIND("(";MyColumn)-1);MyColumn)
```

You can create a view in the list that would show just the calculated column with the correct name.

If you needed the original (and editable) column to contain the correct text you would have to fix the code that creates the list item so that it would set the correct value. If you could not modify the item-creating code you could create an event receiver (with [`ItemAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) and [`ItemUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) events that would fix the field) and register it in your list.

--- Ferda